# How to show image from Firestore Download URL in website

Tags: javascript, html, image, url, google-cloud-firestore

Never before done JavaScript (will learn it sometime), but needed to build this to make the uploading of my data easier into Firebase Firestore for my Android app. I did two tutorials and used that code to build this. The one part uploads the image into Firebase Storage, and then takes the URL and load it into Firebase Firestore with the rest of the data.

It is working 100%, but would like to know how can I make the image show (change HTML or Javascript) instead of the download URL.

This is how I get my output now, I would like the image display there:
[image: This is how it looks now.]

Now where should I put what to display the actual image instead of the URL like in the pic. Is there some thing for web like Picasso or Glide like for Android I have to use to convert the URL into the Image.

I believe somewhere here I should change something or add something to show the image instead of the URL:

Either Here:

```
  //create element and render cafe
  function renderProduct(doc){
let li = document.createElement('li');
let promo_number = document.createElement('span');
let image  = document.createElement('span');
let cross = document.createElement('div');
```

Or Here

```
li.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
promo_number.textContent = doc.data().promo_number;
image.textContent = doc.data().image;
cross.textContent = 'x';
```

Or here

```
li.appendChild(promo_number);
li.appendChild(image);
li.appendChild(cross);

promo_product_list.appendChild(li);
```

But I cannot figure out what to put where.

That is in the Javascript class, please see the JavaScript and HTML in these Pastebins:

[HTML here](https://pastebin.com/dDEPkkjV)

[JavaScript Here](https://pastebin.com/4hmxGjPm)

I know the code is very bad, but it works for what I need it to do, but it will work even better if I can see the actual Image. 
Thanks for looking

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can simply use the [JavaScript DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction#What_is_the_DOM.3F) to dynamically create an `<img />` HTML element whilst specifying the URL, the width, height, etc.

For instance, you could create a reusable function for showing images like such:

```
const displayImg = (url, width, height, id, className) => {
  const img = document.createElement('img');

  img.src = url;
  img.width = width;
  img.height = height;
  img.id = id;
  img.className = className;

  document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

Calling the function above will create an image based on the arguments provided and will append it within the `<body>` tag.